# Servo-amp vs Monolithic

Tags: audio

In the realm of audio what are the differences between servo-amps and monolothic amps? Are there any performances criterion that might make one more favorable to another--gain, noise, ease of implementation, topology, THD, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> what are the differences between servo-amps and monolothic amps?

An audio monolithic amplifier is one component containing all the silicon needed to make an amplifier: -

[image]

As you can see it has five pins (just like an op-amp). A monolithic amplifier is defined by its packaging and not its function.

A servo amplifier may be monolithic (like the one above) or it may be made from discreet components but, in essence it performs a function i.e. it is defined by function and not by packaging.

Providing the amplifier can equally handle DC as well as other audio frequencies it can be a servo amplifier but not all servo amps are either monolithic or capable of handling audio.